# Is the data on flash memory encrypted or unencrypted?

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption

I understand there was full disk encryption from Android 5.5 to 9. Not sure it was ever the default, and not sure what the default is now. I've bricked a Pixel 3 running Android 11, and I want to know whether something crazy like this [flashfixers.com/recover-data-dead-phone-chip-off-data-recovery](https://flashfixers.com/recover-data-dead-phone-chip-off-data-recovery) could recover the data.

I've tried everything else. The device is stuck in a freezing boot loop. I can make it to recovery mode, but sideloading an update through adb doesn't fix it, and I can't use adb to pull data nor fastboot to load TWRP, because I never unlocked the bootloader. Not ever sure unlocking was possible, because it's been on a Verizon payment plan.

Comment: Pixel 3 was released Oct. 2018 with Android 9. And it contains a titan security chip. That device is encrypted by default for sure, I would assume using File Based Encryption. That makes data recovery on flash chip level next to impossible. I assume you are affected by the Pixel 3 a lot people have faced this year: https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2021/09/reports-of-pixel-3s-bricking-with-edl-message-are-growing/

Comment: I got mine October 2019. Would starting out on a later version of android make a difference? By then they were up to 10.0 https://developers.google.com/android/images#blueline

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Couldn't unlock phone and stuck in a reboot loop after my battery completely died once, sideload doesn't fix](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/241229/couldnt-unlock-phone-and-stuck-in-a-reboot-loop-after-my-battery-completely-die)

Comment: I ended up discovering that my two front-facing cameras were plugged back into the wrong slots. I had them flipped around. If I unplug them, the phone starts. If I plug them back in opposite, it starts. Too bad I already factory reset.

Comment: are they modular/removable? kindly post the solution as answer (maybe to the other question?)

Comment: Well it doesn't answer my question, but it solve the issue that was causing me to ask this question. The question is about whether the flash memory is encrypted, and the answer seems to be yes.